# Python: Replace element in list inside list of list, with value from another list in same

Tags: python, list, range

I have a list of lists in python in which I want to replace the first value of some lists with the first value of the list preceding it, but only for certain lists.

```
for i, x in enumerate(protected_rows):
        k = protected_rows[i + 1]
        dup_rows_indx = range(x + 2, k, 2) =
        for j in dup_rows_indx:
            try:
            rows[j][0] = rows[j-1][0]
            else:
            continue
```

basically if my list was

```
rows = [[a, b, c], [d], [e, f, g, h, i], [j, k, l, m], [n], [o, p], [q, r, s], [t, u], [v, w, x]]
```

and `protected_rows = [1, 4]` I want the output to be

```
rows = [[a, b, c], [d], [e, f, g, h, i], [e, k, l, m], [n], [o, p], [o, r, s], [t, u], [t, w, x]]
```

Any help appreciated. Relatedly I also then want to remove `rows[j-1]` but I've completely failed at the first step. Thank you.

Comment: What do you need help with? What does your code produce if you fix the indendation errors?

Comment: Not just indentation errors. You have a random `else` block without an `if`.

Comment: @rcshon `for-else` is actually valid syntax - the OP just isn't using it correctly.

Comment: good point @Paul M. I'll admit  Ididn't know that.

Comment: i get SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call for the dup_rows_indx

Comment: I have the for-else so that the range call doesn't get index error. I am sure I am doing it wrong / there is a better way, would love suggestions.

Comment: Please consider converting list elements to characters. E.g.- `[['a',  'b', 'c' ], ['d, 'e'] ]` This way it will be lot easier for someone to use them in their code .

Comment: When you set `protected_rows = [2, 5]`: Do you actually mean `rows[1]` (`[d]`) and `rows[4]`(`[n]`) - list indexing starts at `0`?

Comment: yes my mistake, protected_rows in the example should read [2, 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for clarification here my view on the sample you've provided:

```py
rows = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d'],                      # < protected row (index: 1)
    ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
    ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm'],
    ['n'],                      # < protected row (index: 4)
    ['o', 'p'],
    ['q', 'r', 's'],
    ['t', 'u'],
    ['v', 'w', 'x']
]
```

My assumption is that `[2, 5]` should be `[1, 4]`. (If you don't want to adjust that then there's an easy fix.)

Now try

```py
protected_rows = [1, 4]
indices = [-1] + protected_rows + [len(rows)]
for i_0, i_1 in zip(indices[:-1], indices[1:]):
    for i in range(i_0 + 2, i_1, 2):
        rows[i][0] = rows[i - 1][0]
```

or (if you want to stick with `[2, 5]`)

```py
protected_rows = [2, 5]
indices = [-1] + [i - 1 for i in protected_rows] + [len(rows)]
for i_0, i_1 in zip(indices[:-1], indices[1:]):
    for i in range(i_0 + 2, i_1, 2):
        rows[i][0] = rows[i - 1][0]
```

to get

```py
rows = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d'],                      # < protected row (index: 1)
    ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],  
    ['e', 'k', 'l', 'm'],       # < first item now 'e'
    ['n'],                      # < protected row (index: 4)
    ['o', 'p'],
    ['o', 'r', 's'],            # < first item now 'o'
    ['t', 'u'],
    ['t', 'w', 'x']             # < first item now 't'
]
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you! (and double thanks for reading through my very dumb and obvious error). Really appreciated, could not wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

**Original Code:**

The code is not reproducible, so I am making an example as I go. Suppose we have a list of lists of integers, and we want to replace the first element of each list with the first element of its predecessor, but only if the replacement candidate is an even number. Here's one way of doing this:

```python
import copy

lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7],[8,9,10],[11,12,13],[14,15]]

#create a copy to change. 
lst2=copy.deepcopy(lst)
lst2

#iterate over both lists
for l,k in zip(lst, lst2[1:]):
    #print (l,k)

    if(k[0]%2==0):
        k[0]=l[0]

print('====')
print(lst2)

# Out:
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 6], [7], [7, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [11, 15]]
```

---

**Edit As per Comment-  See Below**

If, on the other hand, you want to filter alterable lists based on a list of protected indices, then it can be done simply like this :

```
import copy

lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7],[8,9,10],[11,12,13],[14,15]]

protected_rows= [2,4]

#create a copy to change. 
lst2=copy.deepcopy(lst)

#start counting from 1, include final index
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    if(i not in protected_rows ):
        lst2[i][0]=lst2[i-1][0]
        
print(lst) 
#print(protected_rows)
print(lst2)  
#out:
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [14, 15]]
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 6], [7], [7, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [11, 15]]
```

Note: If we don't use a copy , the changes will cascade, i.e. the elements  will be replaced by the altered value in previous list.

Comment: Thank you for this, to me it looks like it doesn't take into account the protected rows. If you look at my example I'm looking for an out  in your example that would read `# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [7, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [11, 15]] assuming lst[2] was my only protected_row.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
rows = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm'], ['n'], ['o', 'p'], ['q', 'r', 's'], ['t', 'u'], ['v', 'w', 'x']]

protected_rows = [2, 5]

for i in range(len(rows)):
    for j in range(len(protected_rows)):
        if i == protected_rows[j]:
            rows[i+1][0] = rows[i][0]
```

for the `rows[j-1]` part please explain in more detail what you need.

output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], ['e', 'k', 'l', 'm'], ['n'], ['o', 'p'], ['o', 'r', 's'], ['t', 'u'], ['v', 'w', 'x']]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong but wouldn't this replace the first element of the row after the protected row, with the 0 value of the protected row? I'm trying to start at the protected rows and replace the first element of every second row after the protected row with the first element from the row preceding it, until the next protected row. Does this help you understand what I'm trying to do w/ rows[j-1]?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added the output so you can see what it does, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I added the output so you can see what it does, let me know if you need anything else @pancakeflip

Comment: Hello Snir, thanks again for this. The missing element is that between protected rows I have variable number of rows that need adjustment. For example in your output I would need the last two lists to read ['t', 'u'], ['t', 'w', 'x']. In the actual data I'm working with there are sometimes 50 rows between protected rows, and sometimes only 2. I've come to a few solutions that are able to produce the output you've given (not as elegantly as yours), however, I'm having trouble having it replace every second rows first element with the first element of the row before it between protected rows.